# SQL Server: use left join to select a column from two tables as a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am trying to build a select query that will essentially left join two tables and display one column from each table as a single column.

the table structure is similar to:

table a:

```
id, email
```

table b:

```
id, tablea_id, email
```

I am trying to get a single column of email and email (with no dupes or nulls ideally).

ideal results would be:

```
one@one.com
two@two.com
three@three.com
```

and the email address that is returned could be from either a or b.

Maybe a union is what would work best, but I not able to figure out how to do a union on the second table based on the id of the first table.

When searching for a solution, perhaps my wording is bad, but I can't find any examples.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you mean that you want the values of a.data and b.data *combined* in the same column, e.g. if a.data = "ABC" and b.data = "DEF", the result = "ABCDEF"? Or do you want to see whichever is not null? Or do you want a separate record for each record in 'a' and in 'b' (in which case you'd use a UNION, not a LEFT JOIN)?

Comment: So, do you want to `JOIN` the tables or do a `UNION`?. What are the values that can't be duplicates?, data?, the ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want something on the lines of this:

```
SELECT email
FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT B.email
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
ON A.id = B.TableA_id
```

Comment: He's not real clear in what he wants, but I think this is very close.

Comment: i didn't see this one until just now, but this is the correct answer as well. sorry my explanation was poor...

Comment: It seems this was answered before Thomas edited his answer. It should be marked as the correct answer imho

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want a unique list of email addresses from either table you can do:

```
Select email
From TableA
Union
Select email
From TableB
```

If you are looking for a unique list of email addresses from Table B and those from Table A that exist in Table B, then you can do:

```
Select TableA.email
From TableA
    Join TableB
        On TableB.TableA_id = TableA.id
Union
Select email
From TableB
```

If, per your comments, you need all rows from Table A and only rows from Table B where they exist in Table A:

```
Select email
From Table A
Union 
Select TableB.email
From TableB
    Join TableA
        On TableA.id = TableB.TableA_id
```

Comment: this produces all rows from table b. i need all rows from table a and only the rows from table b where the tableb_id = tablea_id

thanks

Comment: @Jason - Ok. That's just a variation of my second solution. Have appended that scenario to my solution.

Comment: that last option is the one. i guess it didn't occur to me to think backwards. thanks so much. i was about to go nuts. it was a join and a union, who knew.

Comment: I think the only thing missing is adding `where email is not null` to the predicates of each query in the union: (select email from tableA **where email is not null**) union (select tableB.email from tableB  join tableA on tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id **where tableB.email is not null**)

Comment: @Jason, @arcain - That depends on whether the email columns in the respective tables are declared as nullable. The OP never mentioned one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.email+ ' ' + b.email FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b on a.Id = b.tablea_Id WHERE b.email IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: i am not looking to concat the columns, but more of a union with the email (data) column containing both a and b results

Comment: I'm not grasping the difference between what you want and a concatenation. Are you wanting the ENTIRETY of the results in the one column, as opposed to multiple rows?

Comment: multipe rows, but one column. so if there were 25 a records and 10 b records, there would be 35 rows, one column

Comment: Ah, in that case, it looks like the other folks have beaten me to the punch. Li0liQ's answer below looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

```
SELECT
    id, email
FROM
    a

UNION

(
    SELECT
        a.id AS id, b.email AS email
    FROM
        b
    INNER JOIN
        a
    ON
        a.id = b.tablea_id
) b
```